# SQL Server 2008 R2 multiple cursors within a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

I need to import data from several tables in one database to corr tables in another database.

I tried doing this using multiple cursors within a stored procedure. One cursor for each table.

However, I find it difficult to troubleshoot any errors.

Can anyone suggest some alternate methods to create this type of stored procedure or a way to debug the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff660751).

It was designed to handles these kinds of ETL Scenarios.